# Use multiple files for logs using glog

Tags: go, logging, glog

I'd like to use different directories for different connections. Let's say I have connections that are being handled in separate threads/goroutines. I want them to write to different log directories. I can specify `-log_dir`, but it will write to only one directory, so it's really hard to understand which log file is for.

Is there a way to do something like that using `glog` or another package?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you may have to create separate logger instances (for each goroutine) to write logs to different directories within different goroutines. [Lumberjack](https://github.com/natefinch/lumberjack) would help in this scenario. Its a log rolling package for Go.

```
// Do this for each goroutine
logger := glog.New()
// redirect logs to a different directory
logger.SetOutput(&lumberjack.Logger{
    Filename:   "/var/log/app/goroutine1.log",
    MaxSize:    1,  // megabytes
    MaxBackups: 3,
    MaxAge:     28, // days
})
```